# Can Discord Bot have a notification SFX?

Tags: discord, chatbot

I created a Discord Bot that sends a reminder for the team every hour or so. I want it to produce a new message SFX just like the tone for when someone in the channel sends a message.

Do you know if I can code a notification SFX to my Discord Bot? If yes, can you send me the link to a source code.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge I do not think you can do that, I am not sure if it against TOS or not but yeah, if you want to do it just from the bot then no.